Are there affine rings that are properly affine?
Let $A$ be an abelian group. If $B$ is a nonempty set equipped with a transitive free action of $A$ (written additively), say that $B$ is an affine abelian group (equivalently, $B$ is an $A$-principal homogeneous space or $B$ is an $A$-torsor). Taking affine abelian groups $B$ (over the abelian group $A$) and $D$ (over $C$), say that a map $g: B \to D$ is an affine group homomorphism if there exists a homomorphism $f: A \to C$ such that $\forall a \in A, b \in B: g(b + a) = g(b) + f(a)$. Taking affine abelian groups $A$, $B$ and $C$, say that a map $f: A \times B \to C$ is affinely bilinear if for all fixed $a \in A$, the map $f(a, \cdot): B \to C$ is an affine group homomorphism and for all fixed $b \in B$, the map $f(\cdot, b): A \to C$ is an affine group homomorphism.
We call an affine abelian group $A$ an affine ring if it is equipped with an element $1 \in A$ and an affinely bilinear map $\cdot: A \times A \to A$ such that $\cdot$ is associative and $1$ is a unital element for $\cdot$. Given affine rings $A$ and $B$, say that a map $f: A \to B$ is an affine ring homomorphism if $f$ is an affine group homomorphism, $\forall a_1, a_2 \in A: f(a_1 \cdot a_2) = f(a_1) \cdot f(a_2)$ and $f(1) = 1$. In particular, the affine rings form a category which we might call  $\mathsf{AffRing}$ and there is a notion of isomorphism of affine rings. There is an inclusion $I: \mathsf{Ring} \to \mathsf{AffRing}$.

This means that an affine ring is essentially a "ring that has forgotten its zero element". Has this type of structure been studied anywhere? Does it have a common name? Can you give any reference?
Clearly, any ring is also an affine ring. Is any affine ring isomorphic to a ring, or are there actually affine rings that are properly affine? It is well-known that every affine space is isomorphic to a vector space and similarly every affine abelian group is isomorphic to an abelian group simply by "choosing an arbitrary zero element". However, in the case of affine rings, the zero element is not so arbitrary: It must be an absorbing element with respect to the multiplication. Therefore, we cannot simply "arbitrarily choose a zero element".

I guess the underlying stronger question is whether an affine bilinear map must actually come from a bilinear map for some choice of origins.

A counterexample to that stronger question is the map $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x,y)=2xy+x$.  A bilinear map for some choices of origins would have the form $(x,y)\mapsto a(x+b)(y+c)+d$ for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$, so the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ would have to be divisible by the coefficient $a$ of $xy$.

Any abelian group $A$ can be made into an affine ring by defining $a\cdot b=a+b$ (with unit $0$).  This has no absorbing element and thus is not isomorphic to a ring unless $A$ is trivial.
More generally, if $\mu:A\times A\to A$ is any associative bilinear map, you can make $A$ into an affine ring with unit $0$ by defining $a\cdot b=\mu(a,b)+a+b$.  If this is isomorphic to a ring with the $0$ element of the ring corresponding to an element $x\in A$, that would mean that $A$ becomes a ring with the multiplication $a\cdot b =\mu(a+x,b+x)+a+b+x$  For $0$ to be absorbing with respect to this multiplication, $-x$ must be a two-sided unit with respect to $\mu$ (first setting $a=b=0$ gives $\mu(x,x)=-x$, and then setting $a=0$ or $b=0$ gives that $-x$ is a unit on each side).  So, if $\mu$ does not have a two-sided unit, then this affine ring structure is not isomorphic to a ring.
In fact, every affine ring is of this form.  First, if $A,B,C$ are abelian groups, then any affine bilinear map $f:A\times B\to C$ has the form $f(a,b)=\mu(a,b)+g(a)+h(b)+c$ for some bilinear $\mu:A\times B\to C$, linear $g:A\to C$ and $h:B\to C$, and some element $c\in C$ (namely, $c=f(0,0)$, $g(a)=f(a,0)-c$, $h(b)=f(0,b)-c$, and $\mu(a,b)=f(a,b)-g(a)-h(b)-c$).  Now given an affine ring structure on an abelian group $A$, we can write the multiplication in this form $a\cdot b=\mu(a,b)+g(a)+h(b)+c$. We may assume that the unit is $0$, so setting $a=b=0$ gives $c=0$ and then setting $a=0$ or $b=0$ gives that $g$ and $h$ are the identity $A\to A$, so $a\cdot b=\mu(a,b)+a+b$ for some bilinear $\mu$, which then must be associative in order for $\cdot$ to be associative.
Another perspective on these examples is that if $R$ is a ring and $A\subseteq R$ is a subrng, then $1+A$ becomes an affine ring with additive group $A$ using the multiplication of $R$ (morally, this is something like the "tangent space of $R$ at $1$", if you think of $A$ as the "infinitesimal" elements).  When $A$ is all of $R$, this is just the ring $R$; when the product of any two elements of $A$ is $0$, this is isomorphic to $A$ with the affine ring multiplication $a\cdot b=a+b$.  In general, the affine ring structure on $A$ coming from a bilinear map $\mu$ as above corresponds to the affine ring structure on $1+A$ in the ring $R$ that is obtained from the rng $A$ with multiplication $\mu$ by formally adjoining a unit.
